# Android: WVGA (480x800), width and height in photoshop?

Tags: android

I'm doing visual design for an Android App supporting WVGA.
What should the pixel width and height in Photoshop be?
Does it have to be 480x800? 
Or can I still design in 320x480?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look good, you should do it 480x800. If you do it 320x480, the system will have to scale it. In fact, the aspect ratio of those dimensions are different.